# How shall I launch from lualatex a lua program contained in a lua variable?

Tags: luatex, lua

I store contents in lua variables and use them in a lualatex document. I know how to do insert that content in the TeX flow, in a macro but I don't know how to launch a lua program contained in a lua variable.

```
\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage{luatextra} % pour LuaLaTex  
\begin{document}  
\newcommand{\amacro}[1]{*#1*}  
\luaexec{  
a=1  
atext='stupid text'  
apgm='a=a+1' % the content is a program  
}  
\luaexec{tex.print(atext)} % contents in the TeX flow  : works  
\amacro{\luaexec{tex.print(atext)}} % contents used in a macro : works  
\luaexec{\luaexec{tex.print(apgm)}} % contents used as a program : fails 
\luaexec{tex.print(a)}  
\end{document}
```

How shall I launch the lua program stored in the lua variable apgm ?

Comment: please fix your example so people can run it, it is missing a `\documentclass` line and a definition for `\luaexec` and `\lprint`

Comment: I would guess that you are using the luacode packge but you don't say? the primitive `\directlua` is expandable so more easily nested in this way, but storing the lua expression in a lua string and passing back to tex to be re-evaluated as lua is somewhat unusual (and means you will have lots of issues of quoting any characters special to tex or lua) , what is the actual use case?

Comment: why are you storing a+1 as a string (so needing a nested execution) rather than defining a function? `function apgm (a) return a+1 end` ?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle in fact I store bits of lua programs in a database and get them back to be executed. To be more precise, I insert these programs in a the value of a key-value to have them executed later. So itused to be : ...keyvalue1=\luaexec{a=a+1}, ... and I wish to replace the literal a=a+1 by a lua variable containing "a=a+1".

Comment: but why store a lua function in a lua string rather than a lua function ?  The issue with `\directlua`/`\luaexec` is basically as described in answers to your earlier question https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/284748/lua-to-tex-content-and-variable-content-different  where as egreg explained there, `\luaexec` is not expandable. But here I do not think you needed nested eval at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `load()` function from Lua and load your code stored in `apgm` without tossing it to TeX and back.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{document}

\newcommand{\amacro}[1]{bla#1bla}
\newcommand{\lprint}[1]{\directlua{tex.print(#1)}}
\newcommand{\leval}[1]{\directlua{assert(load(#1))()}}

\luaexec{  
a=1  
atext='stupid text'  
apgm='a=a+1' % the content is a program  
}

\lprint{atext} % contents in the TeX flow  : works  

\amacro{\lprint{atext}} % contents used in a macro : works  

\lprint{a} % prints 1
\leval{apgm} % contents used as a program
\lprint{a} % prints 2
\end{document}
```

Note the `\leval` macro which just loads and immediately executes the code stored in a Lua variable. Assert is helpful in case of syntax errors in the loaded code. Without it the error message becomes too cryptic.

Comment: @David also : I agree that "the natural Lua datatype to hold a program fragment is a function not a string". But I have a string (that come from a database). The key between the two is "load". I understood the propositions of you both thus : I replaced \luadirect{a=a+1} first by \luadirect{function anonymous() a=a+1; anonymous()} and then naturally by \luadirect{load(apgm)()} where apgm="a=a+1" coming from the database. And it works in the real context :)

Comment: @David : avoiding going to TeX and back is a big plus : it avoids problems with special TeX characters.

Answer (score 2):

The use case seems a bit strange and you have not defined `\luaexec` or `\lprint` but I think you want something like this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\newcommand{\amacro}[1]{bla#1bla}

\directlua{  
a=1  
atext='stupid text'  
apgm='a=a+1' % the content is a program  
}

\directlua{tex.print(atext)} % contents in the TeX flow  : works  

\amacro{\directlua{tex.print(atext)}} % contents used in a macro : works  

\directlua{tex.print(a)} % a is 1

\directlua{\directlua{tex.print(apgm)}} % nested lua eval why??????

\directlua{tex.print(a)} % a is 2

 \end{document}
```

---

You can avoid going to tex and back by using `load()` as in Sergei's answer, however the natural Lua datatype to hold a program fragment is a function not a string.

The same output is obtained from the following without needing any nested evaluation.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\newcommand{\amacro}[1]{bla#1bla}

\directlua{  
a=1  
atext='stupid text'  
function apgm () a=a+1 end % the content is a program  
}

\directlua{tex.print(atext)} % contents in the TeX flow  : works  

\amacro{\directlua{tex.print(atext)}} % contents used in a macro : works  

\directlua{tex.print(a)} % a is 1

\directlua{apgm()} %

\directlua{tex.print(a)} % a is 2

 \end{document}
```